# Unable to perform get request in ktor framework

Tags: api, ktor

I am new to ktor and trying to create api in it.As I have downloaded project from `ktor.io` and opened it inside IntelliJ idea community edition then run button is showing disabled and when I am running it on right clicking on `application.kt` file and clicking on run application option.Its showing:

```
ktor.application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

When I am going to this link on webpage it is showing:

```
The web page at http://0.0.0.0:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

Even if I have get route defined below is my code:

**Application.kt**

```
fun main() {
  embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
    configureRouting()
 }.start(wait = true)
}
```

**Routing.kt**

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {
// Starting point for a Ktor app:
routing {
    get("/") {
        call.respondText("Hello World!")
     }
   }
}
```

Someone let me know What is an issue and how can I resolve it.

Comment: Could you please try to use a different port? Also, please try to make a request to a server using `http://localhost:8080` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080` address.

Comment: Thanks man its working fine now but why its not working with  `http://0.0.0.0:8080` as sever has started on the same.

Comment: I have no idea.